# trying to make an arduino blink morse code numbers

Tags: arduino, led

I am trying to make a arduino sketch that takes a number from 0-9 from serial input and blinks a light for that number in morse code. If you don't know moorse code for numbers its very simple heres a pic[image: morse code] 
after the number is blinked the led should blink for 5 seconds and then the program should wait for another number to be input. What the program is doing is waiting for an input, and then blinking continuously forever. it never even getting to the point of blinking for 5 seconds. Here is my code:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Enter a number to be blinked in moose code");

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  if(Serial.available()>0){
   int num=Serial.read();
   delay(2);
   if(num>=0){
      if(num<6){
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
          delay(300);
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  
          delay(300);                       
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   
        }
        for(int i=num; i<5; i++){
          delay(1200);
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  
          delay(1200);                       
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        }
      }
      else{
        for(int i=0; i<(num-5); i++){
          delay(1200);
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  
          delay(1200);                       
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        }
        for(int i=num; i<10; i++){
          delay(300);
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  
          delay(300);                       
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   
        }
      }
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  
      delay(5000);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); 
   }
  }
}
```

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: I would put some Serial.println(num); statements in various places to help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my code there was a problem with the way I was reading the data.

```
long num=0;
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("Enter a number to be blinked in moose code");

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  while(Serial.available()==0){}
  if(Serial.available()>0){
   num=Serial.parseInt();
   delay(2);
   if(num>=0){
      if(num<6){
        for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
          delay(400);
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  
          delay(400);                       
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   
        }
        for(int i=num; i<6; i++){
          delay(400);
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  
          delay(2000);                       
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        }
      }
      else{
        for(int i=0; i<(num-5); i++){
          delay(400);
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  
          delay(2000);                       
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
        }
        for(int i=num; i<10; i++){
          delay(400);
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  
          delay(400);                       
          digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);   
        }
      }
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);  
      delay(5000);
      digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW); 
   }
  }
}
```